# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport from class jakarta.activation.MailcapCommand Map

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, java-17

i get the following error message all at once when using Jakarta.Mail.

```
`Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport from class jakarta.activation.MailcapCommandMap (com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport and jakarta.activation.MailcapCommandMap are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @3697186)
at jakarta.activation.MailcapCommandMap.\<init\>(MailcapCommandMap.java:149)
at jakarta.activation.CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(CommandMap.java:55)
at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.getCommandMap(DataHandler.java:127)
at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:586)
at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:514)
at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1475)
`
```

I use the following versions:

Jakarta-EE: 10.0.0
Jakarta.Mail: 2.1.1
JDK: 17

The error comes when I call the function getContent() from jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.

Does anyone have an idea to fix the error message without using an old version?

Thank you very much for your help

I want to use the getContent() methods in MimeMessage in the latest version